# Mixing python and bash shell's xargs command doubts

Tags: python, bash, xargs

```
system : Centos 6.7 Lasted 
Shell : bash 
python : 2.6.6
```

It makes me very confused! example below:

5 files:

```
a1111  a2222  b1111  b2222  t.py
```

t.py content:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = sys.argv[1]
    print 'id(a1)=%s, len(a1)=%s, str(a1)=%s, type(a1)=%s' % (id(a1), len(a1), str(a1), type(a1))
```

do this like:

```
ls | xargs -I{} echo $(python t.py '{}')
```

output:

```
id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=a1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=a2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=b1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=b2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=t.py, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
```

my question is why len(a1)=2, but str(a1)=a1111 ?， **string length is obviously not equal to 2**，

with no echo is ok, but it's not my question. I have use xargs -p option to print the cmd

```
ls | xargs -I{} python t.py '{}'
```

Comment: Reproduced on OS X on python 2.7.10 and 3.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `$(python t.py '{}')` expression is being evaluated *before* it gets passed to `xargs`. `$(python t.py '{}')` prints "id(a1)=139821454683184, len(a1)=2, str(a1)={}, type(a1)=", so *that* gets passed to `xargs`, which replaces the `{}` with each of the filenames...

Here's a shell trace that shows what's happening:

```
$ set -x # turn on tracing
$ ls | xargs -I{} echo $(python t.py '{}')
+ ls
++ python t.py '{}'
+ xargs '-I{}' echo 'id(a1)=4560222208,' 'len(a1)=2,' 'str(a1)={},' 'type(a1)=<type' ''\''str'\''>'
id(a1)=4560222208, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=a1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4560222208, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=a2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4560222208, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=b1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4560222208, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=b2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4560222208, len(a1)=2, str(a1)=t.py, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
```

The "+" lines show what the shell is actually executing. (You can ignore that the arguments to `xargs` are shown in single quotes; this is just because the output of `t.py` was split into words, but the other shell metacharacters in its output were ignored, and to get the same effect directly on the command line you'd have to quote (/escape) the arguments.)

BTW, there's another giveaway that this is what's happening: the id is the same on each line, but if `t.py` was actually being executed separately for each line, you'd get different ids.

Comment: Nice explanation, another quick example showing the length as ten characters, (while perhaps avoiding unterminated quotes by using find instead) `r=$'length=ten'; find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -I$r -0 echo $(python t.py $r)`

Answer (score 2):

When you are seeing this output:

```
len(a1)=2
```

This is actually length of `replStr` that is being used after `-I` option of `xargs`. This is `{}` hence length is `2`.

If you use a different `replStr`.

```
ls | xargs -I% echo $(python ./t.py '%')
```

then you will see `len=1` in output since length of `%` is `1`.

```
id(a1)=4342949968, len(a1)=1, str(a1)=a1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4342949968, len(a1)=1, str(a1)=a2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4342949968, len(a1)=1, str(a1)=b1111, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4342949968, len(a1)=1, str(a1)=b2222, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
id(a1)=4342949968, len(a1)=1, str(a1)=t.py, type(a1)=<type 'str'>
```

Reason of that is when you use:

```
ls | xargs -I{} echo $(python ./t.py '{}')
```

**you are actually calling python program in a subshell and that is passing literal `{}` to python.**

Here is the debug output to show the same:

```
bash -cx 'ls | xargs -I{} echo $(python ./t.py "{}")' >/dev/null
+ ls
++ python ./t.py '{}'
+ xargs '-I{}' echo 'id(a1)=4460329040,' 'len(a1)=2,' 'str(a1)={},' 'type(a1)=<type' ''\''str'\''>'
```

However of you use:

```
bash -cx 'ls | xargs -I{} python ./t.py "{}"' >/dev/null
+ ls
+ xargs '-I{}' python ./t.py '{}'
```

You can see different behavior in the way xargs is calling python command line.

Comment: It is the length of the parameter string, you don't have to change `-I` to see that:  `ls | xargs -I{} echo $(python3 gash.py ' {} ')` gives a length of 4.  The question is "why?"  The string which python gets in `sys.argv[1]` is not `{}`.  Sorry, but all you have done is to describe the problem, not explain it.

Comment: I've added some debug output as well to show why `str(a1)={}` is not passed to python

Comment: If python is sent a string of 5 characters then why is the length reported as 2.  I don't think you have explained that.  BTW, I can't explain it either.

Comment: python is just getting `{}` or `%` as command line argument when subshell gets created